# Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure on Jenkins CI without any error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jenkins, build, continuous-integration

I have jenkins CI integrated into my project so whenever I push my changes to github it automatically starts the test cases and builds and deploys the project to the server. I am getting this weird error after all the test cases are passed. It also says "tests failed" but shows no test as failed. Can I get to the main problem explicitly as I have no clue what is going wrong.

Stack Trace in the end:

```
Tests Failed
1416 examples, 0 failures

Took 187 seconds (3:07)
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
$ ssh-agent -k
unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
unset SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 78221 killed;
[ssh-agent] Stopped.
[Slack Notifications] found #203 as previous completed, non-aborted build
[Slack Notifications] will send OnRepeatedFailureNotification because build matches and user preferences allow it
Finished: FAILURE
```

My main script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash -ex

bundle exec rubocop
./script/setup_test $@
bundle exec parallel_rspec $@ spec/
bundle exec yarn test:ci
```

Answer (score 0):

Failure is detected by non-zero exit code. You have multiple commands in your script. One of the commands must have returned non-zero exit code.

Comment: Hi @Shashank V, Can you please tell how can I check the exit code for the commands executed? How is it displayed in stack trace?